# iOS Animation stops working when returning from different view

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have some bouncing arrows in my application they simply move up and down for 10 seconds to suggest clicking on a button.  They work fine when the page loads the first time.  When I go past this view and then return to the view the arrows are there but they don't move.  They do however disappear after the ten seconds.

Here is the code that controls the movement this is implemented in ViewDidLoad.

```
//Makes my images move up and down

CABasicAnimation *hover = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
hover.additive = YES;
hover.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero];
hover.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, -20.0)]; 
hover.autoreverses = YES; 
hover.duration = 0.8; 
hover.repeatCount = 30; 

[_imageView.layer addAnimation:hover forKey:@"myHoverAnimation"];
[_imageViewTwo.layer addAnimation:hover forKey:@"myHoverAnimation"];
[_imageViewThree.layer addAnimation:hover forKey:@"myHoverAnimation"];



// Delay execution of my block for 10 seconds.

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
    _imageView.alpha = 0.0;
    _imageViewTwo.alpha = 0.0;
    _imageViewThree.alpha = 0.0;
    _arrowLabel.text = @"";

});
```

This only happens when I return to a page using a segue.

When I use dismissViewControllerAnimated I do not have this problem.

What is the difference that makes this occur?

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more. Are you calling `dismissViewController` on the Animation view when you are about to show other view ?.

Comment: No,  This view works fine. Once I leave this view and try to return to it from another view is when I have problems.  I have two other views that return to the original one returns via segue the other via dismissViewController.

Comment: Do you have this in the view did load method?

Comment: Move that code to -viewDidAppear

Comment: Matt that fixes the problem but isn't viewDidLoad called when returning to the view either way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this animation code to viewDidAppear to get the functionality you are looking for.

`viewDidLoad` is only (typically) called once during the lifetime of your view controller, when it is first loaded into memory.  If you dismiss this view controller from a modal context, it (should) get completely removed from memory and is reloaded the next time you present it.

If you return to it from another view controller, it may still have been in memory, just not visible and so `viewDidLoad` won't be called.  One common example of this is if you push ViewControllerB over top of your ViewControllerA containing this animation, ViewControllerA is still in memory.  Its a part of the NavigationController's `viewControllers`.  When you pop ViewControllerB and return to ViewControllerA it appears on screen, but it doesn't get reloaded.